# Full text search with substrings

Tags: full-text-search

I have a table of about ~10M rows, each contains a (unique) sentence.
I'm looking for ways on how to be able to offer fast full-text search that's also supports substrings, prefixes and suffixes,
preferably something lightweight that I can run on the user's desktop.

I've looked at SQLite FTS4, SphinxSearch and other MySQL text searches, but they all seem to not be able to support substring search. Any ideas for good, lightweight solutions?

I'm doing a one-time insert (that can take as long as needed) and then just reading from the database (searches).

Thanks in advance!